# Jquery scrolling out/in text box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a scrolling box that is working fine * [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/gorsky/E9Bq2/1/) * as long as I do not have a huge content under it such as:

```
<article class="content">                                                                           
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a title="Video" href=".php">
                                <img alt="" src=".jpg" width="200" height="124"/>
                                <span>video</span>
                                <strong>Motion Graphics</strong>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                                                    <li>
                            <a title="Video" href=".php">
                                <img alt="" src=".jpg" width="200" height="124"/>
                                <span>video</span>
                                <strong>Motion Graphics</strong>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a title="Video" href=".php">
                                <img alt="" src=".jpg" width="200" height="124"/>
                                <span>video</span>
                                <strong>Motion Graphics</strong>
                            </a>
                        </li>
```

**Problem**
When I do have a bunch of content the scrolling box does not behave properly. It behaves as the first [Scrolling babe scrolling](http://jsfiddle.net/eMYJx/9/) content. It moves weirdly from top to bottom and does not scroll down properly.

I can not understand why is not working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing here, but do you mean this problem is only happening in Opera? If so, then it is because of this line:

```
$('html, body').animate(...);
```

The problem is that Opera will animate first the html, then animate the body. I found an [elegant solution here](http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/01/18/jquery-smooth-scroll-bugs.html) which essentially provides this bit of code:

```
var scrollElement = 'html, body';
$('html, body').each(function(){
  var initScrollTop = $(this).attr('scrollTop');
  $(this).attr('scrollTop', initScrollTop + 1);
  if ($(this).attr('scrollTop') === initScrollTop + 1) {
    scrollElement = this.nodeName.toLowerCase();
    $(this).attr('scrollTop', initScrollTop);
    return false;
  }
});
scrollEl = $(scrollElement);

// further down, when you animate
scrollEl.animate(...);
```

Comment: That looks good but it is happening across all browsers, safari, firefox, opera, etc. Thanks!

Comment: I can see the problem now. It happens when the page reach the full height and then scroll totop as showed in: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/eMYJx/

Comment: scrollTop will be zero until the page reaches full height. So you might need to do something with `$(window).height()` as well.